# What is the 'holding lines' here?

Tags: word-meaning

This is from [an article](http://www.cbc.ca/news/canada/nova-scotia/georges-bank-offshore-oil-and-gas-fisheries-whales-1.4483926) in the CBC news.

> CBC contacted three Canadian government departments — Global Affairs
>   Canada, Natural Resources Canada and the Department of Fisheries and
>   Oceans — for a response.
>
> A spokesperson for Natural Resources issued the **holding lines** —
>   talking points put out when you don't want to, or cannot, address an
>   issue in detail.

I googled 'holding line(s)' and had no luck. The closest I can find is '**hold the line**' which means 'to firmly maintain something' and I don't think that's the case here. What is the '**holding lines**' here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is defined in the paragraph that you quote. A holding line is a statement issued (by a government department for example) in response to a question (from a journalist, for example) that acknowledges the question but doesn't attempt to answer it in detail.

To paraphrase from the article:

> *What will the Canadian government do about American oil exploration on fishing grounds in the North Atlantic?*
>
> We recognise the environmental sensitivity of the area, and the importance of fishing to Nova Scotia. We will monitor developments, but we won't speculate on what the Americans will do next.

The response is a holding line. The journalist has a response, but not an answer to the question. The response is careful to say nothing of significance.

Comment: Do you get to see and hear 'holding line' a lot? Is this a usual set expression?

Comment: No, it unusual, I've never seen it before, this is why it is defined in the article. Readers are not expected to know this term. It might be jargon used in journalism. I understanding from the definition in the article, and the usual meanings of "holding" and "lines".

Answer (score 1):

It appears this article is using "holding lines" as a synonym or near-synonym to the term "holding statements," which are the "initial statement(s) designed to help control the message to the public immediately following an incident." (BCMpedia.org)